# Combine parallel processing with swim lanes?

Tags: plantuml

I want to build something like this using PlantUML:

[image]

But I'm only able to build this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
@startuml
start
:Init;
fork
:Treatment 1;
fork again
:Treatment 2;
end fork
@enduml
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand Activity Diagrams

- you can parallelize things into swimlanes, but there's only one start
- everything has to be in a swimlane (so I proposed "Control" as the start of your diagram)
- PlantUML (and maybe UML in general) expects you to have a join after a fork (which again, I did in the "Control" lane):

```
@startuml
|Control|
:Init;
fork
|#AntiqueWhite|Swimlane1|
'start
:foo1;
'stop
fork again
|Swimlane2|
'start
:foo2;
:foo3;
'stop
|Control|
end fork
stop
@enduml
```

[image]

The PlantUML layout also isn't ideal, since the fork line stays only in the swimlane of the Control process.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by combining an extra column for forking and hiding the start arrows:

[image]

```
@startuml
| | 
|a| Swim1
|b| Swim2
|c| Swim3
| |
fork
|a|
-[hidden]->
start
    if (A?) then (no)
        stop
    else (yes)
        if (B?) then (no)
            stop
        else (yes)
            :C;
        endif
    endif
stop
fork again
|b|
-[hidden]->
start
    :Process 2;
stop
fork again
|c|
-[hidden]->
start
    :Process 3;
stop
| |
end fork
@enduml
```

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add

```
skinparam activityBarColor white
skinparam swimlaneBorderColor white
```

to [Mazzy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74139004/2888219)'s answer, if you don't mind missing borders of the lanes and don't need additional forks in your diagram.

[image: rendered]

or invert the lane background color

[image: rendered]

Answer (score -1):

Not a complete solution but:

```
@startuml
start
:Init;
fork
start
:Treatment 1;
end
fork again
start
:Treatment 2;
end
end fork
@enduml
```

see also:

- the code through the plantuml web server:
  http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SoWkIImgAStDuG8pkAmyyp9BhBdIyekoOI8XHQc99RcfUIKAXjPSgNafO4c5nFJ4p3nC9KPW9I2i03R30SW2cWu0
- the corresponding png:

[image]

Comment: At the downvoter. what is the reason (seen also the remark: "Not a complete solution" at the beginning of the answer)?